# android custom shape as background drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, design-patterns, drawable, shapes

I am trying to draw the blue shape below.
I want my dialog to have this custom blue shape. But I can not figure out.
I have tried the below code.

I really appreciate your tips, Thanks

```
<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="0">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/red_color" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>

</item>

<item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-10"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toDegrees="-10">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/gray_color" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

[image]

To show the inclination 
[image]

This is the result from my code above:
[image]

Comment: Whats the issue you have created the shape but dont know how to show it on a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <color android:color="@android:color/white"/>
</item>

<item android:top="87dp"
    android:bottom="-300dp"
    android:left="0dp"
    android:right="-300dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-10"
        android:pivotX="0%"
        android:pivotY="100%">
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid
                android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

Using the above code you will achieve the inclination. Note: change the color code as you need.
Upvote the code if you find it useful.